# Sort 'Quick Launch' in alphabetical order - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, quicklaunch

Just a quick question about the 'Quick Launch' panel in SharePoint 2010

Is it possible to remove document libraries from the quick launch panel?

Also is it possible to sort the 'Quick Launch' in alphabetical order?

I have been through the settings in the 'Look and feel' tab - There must be a better way of sorting your document libraries than selecting the order manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this by going to site actions>site settings then navigation. You'll see  in the navigation editing and sorting part, the current navigation is the quick launch navigation. You could freely remove every single one of the items and change them with the links you want. Unfortunately, you can't arrange them in alphabetical order in an instant.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - I can't believe you can't sort alphabetically it would be very useful.

Comment: Unfortunately not but yeah, it would be very useful :) do mark this as answer if this answers all your inquiries :)

Comment: Sorry! Accepted now. Answered all my questions :)

Answer (score 3):

To sort the left nav alphabetically within headings (at least in SP 2010):

1. Click **Site Actions > Site Settings**.
2. Under **Look and Feel**, click **Navigation**.
3. In the **Sorting** section, click **Sort automatically**. The **Automatic Sorting** section will appear.
4. In the **Automatic Sorting** section, set the sorting options you want.
5. Click **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me you can sort them, by re-arranging the number. 
Follow this step:
Site Action - Site Settings - Quick Launch - in the menu at the top of the page select change order.

There you will be able too number the order you want your list in.

Comment: No "Quick Launch" entry appears on the Site Action -> Site Settings page in my SP site.  Is this something that requires special rights?